# Display lightning-checkbox-group horizontally

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

**Below is the Screenshot of my lightning-checkbox-group. Instead of showing them vertically I want them aligned horizontally. I have referred several links and applied many CSS but still no luck. Can someone please help me with this. Also I want the background color and border color of the checkboxes to be changed?**

[image]

*.html*

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
            <div class="slds-m-bottom_x-large slds-theme_default slds-form-element__control green-checkbox">
                <lightning-checkbox-group class="green-checkbox" options={objectFieldOptions} value={selectedObjectFieldValue}
                    onchange={objectFieldHandleChange} required="true">
                </lightning-checkbox-group>
            </div>
            </div>
```

**For Bg color and border color change I tried this CSS but it's not working**

*.CSS*

```
.THIS input[type=checkbox]:checked.green-checkbox{
    border-color: #00b200; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #006A00; 
    background-color: rgb(0, 178, 0);
    border:1px solid;
}

.THIS .slds-checkbox {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: @TusharSharma I already tried that but it did not work.

Comment: You say that you've tried `display: inline !important;` but your code doesn't show it.  Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @DavidCheng Yes I have actually tried it. I have updated my code you can check. After adding CSS class do i have to do something in HTML also so that my ```lightning-checkbox-group``` inherits the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to change the display of the lightning-components-* due to [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom).
You probably are better of simply iterating over an array of objects in your template to render a group of checkboxes using an [slds blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/).

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <div class="slds-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="checkbox-unique-id-73" value="checkbox-unique-id-73" checked="" />
      <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="checkbox-unique-id-73">
        <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox Label</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

simply add your event handlers on inputChange and you should be able to modify the css freely.